# Não consigo atribuir função javascript somente quando existir anexo

Tags: javascript, c#

Tenho esse código:

```
<strong><a <%# Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento").ToString()) ? String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("DsPathDocumento"), "'") : "style='cursor: default; color:#000000;'" %>>
                        <%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento")%>
                    </a></strong>
```

Acontece que eu preciso aplicar um javascript, através dessa classe: `class="linkUpload"`
Essa classe só pode acontecer, quando eu criar o hyperlink, caso contrário a classe não pode ser chamada. Toda tentativa minha de colocar essa classe não funcionou. Se eu colocar logo após o a, tipo: `<strong><a class="linkUpload" <%# Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && ...</a></strong>`, quando eu tiver documento ele chama o popup, ok, correto e quando eu não tiver link, também chama o popup em branco. Ele sempre monta o href, mesmo sem documento anexo, como já discuti aqui no SOPT. Abaixo meu javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.linkUpload').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "scrollbars=yes");
        });
    });
```

A pergunta é: Como eu faço para atribuir o javascript na classe somente quando houver documento anexo.

Assim: Se eu possuo documento anexo, a expressão ternária acima no post, deverá executar a etapa após o símbolo "?" e caso não possui anexo, então executa a etapa após o ":", certo? Bem, acontece que de qualquer forma e não sei porque, ele está criando o underline referente ao href mesmo quando não existe anexo. Eu tenho a classe "linkUpload" que deveria ser executada somente quando há anexo. Se eu coloco essa classe logo após a tag "a", ela fica valendo para todas as situações na expressão ternária, ou seja, com ou sem anexo e eu não consigo chamar uma expressão ou comando html de dentro das tags do Asp.Net, então gerou o post: Como eu faço para atribuir a função apenas quando houver link, ou seja, somente quando a primeira parte da expressão ternária for executada.

O que eu quero é isso, ou algo semelhante. Tenho essa tag asp.net: `<% %>`. Como eu chamaria essa classe: `class="linkUpload"` dentro da tag asp.net?

Tentei fazer um if para atender melhor, acho, e não estou conseguindo. Tentei de várias maneiras e essa forma foi a última tentativa antes desse post.

```
<%if(Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento").ToString()))
                      { %>
                      <strong><a class="linkUpload" 
                      <% String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("DsPathDocumento"), "'") %>>
                      </a></strong> <%}%>
                      <%else
                      { %>                      
                      "style='cursor: default; color:#000000;'"
                      Eval("NmTipoDocumento")
                      <%}%>
```

Alterei para essa forma e deu o seguinte erro:

```
<% if(Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento").ToString()))
                      {%>
                      <strong><a class="linkUpload" 
                      <% String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("DsPathDocumento"), "'"); %>>
                      </a></strong> <%}%>
                      <%else
                      { %>                      
                      <"style='cursor: default; color:#000000;'">
                      Eval("NmTipoDocumento")
                      <%}%>
```

Esse é o erro:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

Comment: Olá, poderia explicar um pouco melhor?

Comment: Fiz uma edição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso funciona?

```
<strong>
  <a <%# 
    Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento").ToString()) 
        ? String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("DsPathDocumento"), "'") 
        : "style='cursor: default; color:#000000;'" %>>
    <%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento")%>
  </a>
</strong>
```

Então seria apenas adicionar `class="linkUpload"` depois do `href` no seu elemento `a`, ficaria assim:

```
<strong>
  <a <%# 
    Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento").ToString()) 
        ? String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("DsPathDocumento"), "'", " class='linkUpload'") 
        : "style='cursor: default; color:#000000;'" %>>
    <%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento")%>
  </a>
</strong>
```